# UITableView and UICollectionView with one section doesn't show UIRefreshControl when section have 0 rows / items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I've a page that show content in `UITableView` or in `UICollectionView` (the user can switch between this two elements with a button). All content are showed in one section.

As I wrote in the title, when the section has 0 row (in case of `UITableView`) or 0 items (in case of `UICollectionView`) I can't be able to pull down to refresh using the `UIRefreshControl`.

```
    self.tableViewRefreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.tableViewRefreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(didValueChangedTableViewRefreshControl) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.tableViewRefreshControl];
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (put it in `viewDidLoad` of your `UITableViewController`):

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: NSLocalizedString(@"Release to Refresh", nil)];

[refreshControl addTarget: self
                   action: @selector(refresh:)
         forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```